# Jquery animation-action after action

Tags: jquery-animate

```
$(".Menu_Tab").live(      
    'mouseover',          
    function()            
    {                     
        $(this).animate(  
        {"top": "130px"}, 
        1000);             
    }                     
);
```

This is my code...as you can see "mouseover" changing the position of $(#.Menu_Tab).
My question is-If for example I want to change the color of $(#.Menu_Tab),but only
after the change of a position,how I'm doing that...

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/animate/, especially the `complete` parameter/option.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".Menu_Tab").live(
    'mouseover',          
    function()            
    {                     
        $(this).animate(  
            {"top": "130px"}, 
            1000,
            function() {
                $(this).css("color", "blue");
            }
        );
    }
);
```